# Why getting error while adding Local jar into Maven Spring Boot project uisng mvn install:install-file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to add local jar into maven spring boot project and i am getting error as below:

### Command which i have executed as below:

```
mvn install:install-file –Dfile='D:\WS\APP_Latest\app\lib\Services.jar' -DgroupId=Services -DartifactId=Services -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Executing the above command in POM.xml directory and local jar(Services.jar) present in D:\WS\APP_Latest\app\lib\Services.jar path.

Error as below:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'ûDfile='D' in the current project and in the
 plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
repositories [local (C:\Users\***\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.mav
en.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

can anyone please help on this issue.

Comment: `'ûDfile='D'` seems to be the suspect on a first look. Can you share snapshot from your pom.xml around the above quoted string to help you with what's wrong ?

Comment: Seems to be problem with special characters in your argument i.e `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably copied and pasted the `-Dfile` from somewhere, and the dash `-` in your line is not the "real" dash, but some other dash. Try to retype all the `-` in your expression.

Comment: Aftre replacing - getting another error as "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5
.2:install-file (default-cli) on project app: Error installing artifact 'Services:Services:jar': Failed to install artifact Services:
Services:jar:1.0: D:\***\** (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]". Please help me on this. Thanks. @JF Meier

Comment: Any problems with maven version as i am using 3.5 of maven version.@JF Meier

Comment: Your D:*** stands for `D:\WS\APP_Latest\app\lib\Services.jar`, right? Then you do not have a Maven problem, but a problem in accessing that device.

Comment: Now getting Build Success but it was saying that pom.xml not found in Services.jar while executing mvn install:install-file command. Please help me. @JF Meier

Comment: This just means that there is no given pom.xml. This is usually no problem. Unless you have a separate `Services.pom`, you should be fine.

Comment: Getting warning while building entire application that "The POM for Services:Services:jar:1.0 is missing, no d
ependency information available" and dependency added in pom.xml same as below:<dependency>
 <groupId>Services</groupId>
 <artifactId>Services</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> and also able to see jar in maven dependencies. Thanks. @JF Meier

Comment: The pom should have been created automatically.

Comment: No,That dependency above one i have added after install file. now trying to build entire application and it's getting warning as "The POM for Services:Services:jar:1.0 is missing, no d ependency information available". Thanks. @JF Meier

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question because this discussion is really not about your original question any more.

Comment: please try appending with `-DgeneratePom=true` in you mvn command to generate the pom.xml

Comment: @RajeswariReddy Could you please accept my answer if it solved your original problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ``` in the `-Dfile` argument:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\WS\APP_Latest\app\lib\Services.jar -Dg
roupId=Services -DartifactId=Services -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: Even facing same issue as above ""[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5 .2:install-file (default-cli) on project app: Error installing artifact 'Services:Services:jar': Failed to install artifact Services: Services:jar:1.0: D:*** (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]". Thanks. @piy26

Comment: Can you try appending `--debug` at the end of the command to see in detail what's prohibiting the copy operation.